# I want to draw the figure using TikZ in a beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I want to draw the figure using TI*k*Z in a `beamer` slide.

I have tried like this

```
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.47]
        \tikzset{%
            every matrix/.style={%
                inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                matrix of math nodes,
                column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                nodes={draw=red,font=\color{blue}\footnotesize,minimum size=.55cm,anchor=center},
                ampersand replacement=\&}
        } 
        \matrix[above] (t1) at (0,0) {\cdots \& K \& \cdots\\};
        \matrix[below] (b1) at (0,0) {\cdots \& \bullet \& \bullet \& \& \cdots\\}; 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: \begin{figure}
 \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.47]
  \tikzset{every matrix/.style={inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,matrix of math nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,nodes={draw=red,font=\color{blue}\footnotesize,minimum size=.55cm,anchor=center},ampersand replacement=\&}}
  \matrix[above] (t1)  at (0,0) {\cdots \&  K \& \cdots\\};
  \matrix[below] (b1)  at (0,0) {\cdots \&  \bullet \& \bullet \&   \& \cdots\\};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

Comment: Please add this to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.47]
        \tikzset{%
            every matrix/.style={%
                inner sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                matrix of math nodes,
                column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
                nodes={draw=red,font=\color{blue}\footnotesize,minimum size=.55cm,anchor=center},
                ampersand replacement=\&}
        } 
        \matrix[above] (t1) at (0,0) {\cdots \& K \& \cdots\\};
        \matrix[below] (b1) at (0,0) {\cdots \& \bullet \& \bullet \& \& \cdots\\};
        \draw[blue] (b1-1-2.center) -- ++ (-1,-2) node[pos=1.25] {$A_i$};
        \draw[blue] (b1-1-3.center) -- ++ (1,-2) node[pos=1.25] {$A_j$};
        \node[align=left,blue] at (7,0) {%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{:\ }l@{}}
            $K$ & key\\
            $A_i,A_j$ & something else
        \end{tabular}};
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]